# Use Mono.NET Library in Linux

Tags: .net, c++, linux, macos, mono

First of all, I'd like to point out that I have no experience using Mono.NET, so bear with me if the questions are silly.

I'm working on an application that is written in native C++ code and works in Windows (VS2008) and Linux/Mac (gcc). There is a library that I am looking to integrate with, which is currently compiled in MS.NET (version 2.x).

I have researched and found that I can call into the library using the CCW interface that MS provides. Hence, there shouldn't be too many implementation woes in Windows.

My question is, if I manage to compile the library with the Mono .NET in Linux or Mac, how would I call into that code from my native application? I guess a shorter question may be, is it possible to compile libraries with the Mono compiler that can be called from native C++ code on non-Windows platforms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you would have to [embed Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono). Your native "host" app would have to initialize the Mono runtime then look up and execute MonoMethods on MonoObjects.

Note that because of [P/Invoke](http://www.mono-project.com/PInvoke) it's a lot easier to call C APIs (i.e with `extern "C"` if you use C++) from Mono than it is to call Mono code from C. So your best strategy IMO is make a small C# "glue" library that does a lot of the interop work and exposes a simpler API for your C++ code to use.

For example, you might structure it so the host can call a static method in the glue library which would then create and manipulate objects from the library you're using, and make callbacks into the native host using P/Invoke.

There are also several tricks you can use with "unsafe" code in C# to simplify things - for example, the host could pass IntPtr values (pointers) into the C# glue library, then in an unsafe C# context you could cast them to pointers to C# structs with layouts matching the host's structs, and write directly into the host's structs.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to ahead of time compile the mono library so that it is fully native, eliminating the need for the mono runtime after it has been compiled? See http://www.mono-project.com/AOT